# How to hide the status bar in an AVPlayerViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3, avplayer

i wanna know if this can be done, i'm working on IOS 10, xCode 8 and swift 3, i  tried various solutions from here but none works:

i tried to override the `prefersStatusBarHidden`, i tried to assign a false value but it's a get-only property and in appdelegate, i can't do this:

```
   application.statusBarHidden = true
```

finally, i set in the plist the following:

- Status bar is initially hidden to YES View
- View controller-based status bar appearance to NO

and had no effect, i believe that all this solutions don't work because the upgrade to IOS 10.

Comment: I'd recommend just writing your own. In my experience as soon as you need to modify the stock behavior in one of these ready rolled classes it's time to roll your own.

Comment: yeah, it's what i thought, but, because it's the only change that i need, i would like to use the native player, but maybe i will have to write my own, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Even after hiding the status bar for the entire app using:

```
application.isStatusBarHidden = true
```

AVPlayerViewController still showed the status bar. On going back to the presenting view controller (for which status bar was hidden earlier) status bar became visible. Tried to override  **prefersStatusBarHidden** on both presenting and presented view controllers to no avail.

The only thing that worked was using deprecated method **setStatusBarHidden** in the presenting view controller's **viewWillAppear** method.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarHidden(true, with: .none)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the status bar in any or all of your view controllers just by adding this code:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Any view controller containing that code will hide the status bar by default.

If you want to animate the status bar in or out, just call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` on your view controller – that will force `prefersStatusBarHidden` to be read again, at which point you can return a different value. If you want, your call to `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` can actually be inside an animation block, which causes the status bar to hide or show in a smooth way.

from: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-hide-the-status-bar

Comment: This didn't work for me. But...I found success by extending the AVPlayerController class with `override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { return true }`. And then the status bar stopped showing up. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
     get {
         return true;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply subclass the AVPlayerViewController:

```swift
class PlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController {
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

and use `PlayerViewController()`

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using extension of AVPlayerViewController:
Add the following line to AVPlayerViewController

```
extension AVPlayerViewController{
    override open var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this steps:

In info.plist file set
`View controller-based status bar appearance = NO`

in AppDelegate.swift file

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

 // use this code to hide status bar
    application.isStatusBarHidden = true

    return true
 }
```

This codes enough to hide status bar in swift 3.

Comment: it doesn't work in my case, i have to tell that in all the other views, the status bar hides just fine, but in the case of the AVPlayerViewController, i can't hide it, it is possible? o do i have to make my own player?